# How to extract the contents of a sub node, TreeView

Tags: vb.net, treeview, nodes

I have a treeview in the following format:

```
Item1
--Description1
Item2
--Description2

Etc
```

I've got the following piece of code:

```
TextBox1.text = TreeView.Nodes(0).ToString
```

This puts the contets of Node 1 (In this case "Item1") into the text box.

However, if I put `Nodes(1).ToString`, it will put "Item2" into the text box.

My question is, how can I get the contents of the first sub-node?

I would like "Description1" to be placed in the TextBox.

Thanks.

[Edit]
Also, how can I strip off the `"TreeNode: "` tag that seems to be generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the child nodes by accessing the [nodes property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.nodes(v=vs.110).aspx). In your case, it would be:

```
TreeView.Nodes(0).Nodes(0).ToString
```

If you want to store specific information for a node, you can do it through the [Tag property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) or just use [substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the part of the string you want.

Comment: That works perfectly! I knew it was something stupidly easy.

Thanks.